# Hive cross product of data in an array

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table with 1 column that looks like this

```
    mycol
    [1,2] 
    [5,4,9] 
    [1]
    [1,5,6,7,8]
```

Where the size of the array is not fix --

How can I return the cross product of the data within the array, to where I have something like this:

```
    col1, col2 
     1      1
     1      2 
     1      3 
     1      4 
     1      5 
     2      1
     2      1 
     5      4 
     5      5
     5      4
     5      9
```

etc..

The goal is to be able to have a graph to run jacard similarity on. Im thinking something like this:

```
    SELECT myCol  FROM exampleTable
     LATERAL VIEW explode(col1) myTable1 AS myCol1
     LATERAL VIEW explode(col1) myTable2 AS myCol2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
CREATE VIEW test AS
SELECT myCol  FROM exampleTable
LATERAL VIEW explode(col1) myTable1 AS myCol;
```

then

> select t1.myCol,t2.myCol from test t1 join test t2 on true;